# Ubuntu14.04 First time make whole Android 8.1 or 9 project on QCOM platform failed with abl.elf

Tags: android, linux

I make Android N or P project on QCOM platform first time, it fails immediately with errors as follow:

[  0% 106/102275] build out/target/product/XXXX/abl.elf
FAILED: out/target/product/XXXX/abl.elf 
/bin/bash -c "make -j4 -C bootable/bootloader/edk2      BOOTLOADER_OUT=../../../out/target/product/XXXX/obj/ABL_OBJ         all         BUILD_SYSTEM_ROOT_IMAGE=1       VERIFIED_BOOT=0         VERIFIED_BOOT_2=1       VERIFIED_BOOT_LE=0      USER_BUILD_VARIANT=0        DISABLE_PARALLEL_DOWNLOAD_FLASH=0       CLANG_BIN=/home/abc/3tb_volume/projects/PROJECT_QP/vendor/qcom/proprietary/llvm-arm-toolchain-ship/6.0/bin/         CLANG_PREFIX=/home/abc/3tb_volume/projects/PROJECT_QP/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/bin/aarch64-linux-android-      ABL_USE_SDLLVM=true         ABL_SAFESTACK=true      SAFESTACK_SUPPORTED_CLANG_VERSION=6.0       CLANG_GCC_TOOLCHAIN=/home/abc/3tb_volume/projects/PROJECT_QP/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9      TARGET_ARCHITECTURE=AARCH64         BOARD_BOOTLOADER_PRODUCT_NAME=XXXX"

...

make[1]: *** read jobs pipe: Bad file descriptor.  Stop.
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/abc/3tb_volume/projects/PROJECT_QP/out/target/product/XXXX/obj/ABL_OBJ/Build/DEBUG_CLANG35/AARCH64/ArmPkg/Library/BaseMemoryLibStm/BaseMemoryLibStm'

build.py...
 : error 7000: Failed to execute command
    make tbuild [/home/abc/3tb_volume/projects/PROJECT_QP/bootable/bootloader/edk2/../../../out/target/product/XXXX/obj/ABL_OBJ/Build/DEBUG_CLANG35/AARCH64/ArmPkg/Library/BaseMemoryLibStm/BaseMemoryLibStm]

build.py...
 : error F002: Failed to build module
    /home/abc/3tb_volume/projects/PROJECT_QP/bootable/bootloader/edk2/ArmPkg/Library/BaseMemoryLibStm/BaseMemoryLibStm.inf [AARCH64, CLANG35, DEBUG]

- Failed -
  Build end time: 11:08:39, Oct.30 2018
  Build total time: 00:00:01

make: *** [makefile:133: ABL_FV_IMG] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/abc/3tb_volume/projects/PROJECT_QP/bootable/bootloader/edk2'
[  0% 109/102275] target thumb C++: memory_replay_tests_32 <= system/extras/memory_replay/Action.cpp
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
11:08:40 ninja failed with: exit status 1

failed to build some targets (01:23 (mm:ss))

---

I have checked the "bootable/bootloader/edk2" directory with command:
. edksetup.sh

The result is OK!

abc@abc:~/3tb_volume/projects/PROJECT_QP/bootable/bootloader/edk2$ . edksetup.sh
Loading previous configuration from /home/abc/3tb_volume/projects/PROJECT_QP/bootable/bootloader/edk2/Conf/BuildEnv.sh
WORKSPACE: /home/abc/3tb_volume/projects/PROJECT_QP/bootable/bootloader/edk2
EDK_TOOLS_PATH: /home/abc/3tb_volume/projects/PROJECT_QP/bootable/bootloader/edk2/BaseTools
CONF_PATH: /home/abc/3tb_volume/projects/PROJECT_QP/bootable/bootloader/edk2/Con

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this issue as well. I found the solution here:
https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/10780137/ 
It is not the same code but the problem is the exact same problem.

The issue is that the command is expecting to inherit file descriptors from previous commands, but by default in make this does not happen. So you need to add the '+' to that line in the edk2 makefile Here is the patch I used to get it to work:

```
--- a/makefile  2019-09-25 13:00:28.064160817 -0500
+++ b/makefile  2019-09-25 13:00:34.957369325 -0500

@@ -129,7 +129,7 @@
    $(MAKEPATH)make -C $(EDK_TOOLS) $(PREBUILT_HOST_TOOLS) -j1

 ABL_FV_IMG: EDK_TOOLS_BIN
-   @. ./edksetup.sh BaseTools && \
+   +@. ./edksetup.sh BaseTools && \
    build -p $(WORKSPACE)/QcomModulePkg/QcomModulePkg.dsc \
    -a $(ARCHITECTURE) \
    -t $(TARGET_TOOLS) \
```